# KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.Europe.OSGB1936 showing as WGS84 in Visual Studio

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, dotspatial

I'm trying to get my head around DotSpatial.
I'm specifically trying to convert the geographic points of a feature from OSGB1936 (27700) to WGS84.
This is the line of C# that I was hoping would do the conversion:

```
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(polygonPoints, z, KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.Europe.OSGB1936,
KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984, 0, feature.Coordinates.Count);
```

The coordinates after conversion are incorrect (all are the value 8).
In Visual Studio if I hover over `KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.Europe.OSGB1936` I get "{WGS84}" returned from Visual Studio suggesting it has evaluated that expression to that coordinate system. DotSpatial is recognising `KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.Europe.OSGB1936`, i.e. it is not highlighting as an error and stopping execution, but it seems to be ignoring it and returning WSG84 instead.

I've tried installing other NuGet DotSpatial packages like `DotSpatial.Projections` and have searched the web but cannot find out why. I feel like I'm missing some definitions somewhere.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the original code above does not work but the following worked for me:

```
Shapefile shapefile = Shapefile.OpenFile("aShapeFile.shp");
ProjectionInfo source = shapefile.Projection; 
ProjectionInfo destination = ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(4326); 

double[] polygonPoints = new double[1];
double[] z = new double[1];

IFeature feature = null;
for (int i = 0; i < shapefile.NumRows(); i++)
{
    feature = shapefile.GetFeature(i);
    
    Array.Resize<double>(ref polygonPoints, feature.Coordinates.Count * 2);
    Array.Resize<double>(ref z, feature.Coordinates.Count * 2);
    int idx = 0;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < feature.Coordinates.Count; ix++)
    {
        polygonPoints[idx] = feature.Coordinates[ix].X;
        polygonPoints[idx + 1] = feature.Coordinates[ix].Y;
        z[ix] = 1;
        idx = idx + 2;
    }
    //polygonPoints array at this point is in OSGB1936
    Reproject.ReprojectPoints(polygonPoints, z, source, destination, 0, feature.Coordinates.Count);
    //polygonPoints array is now in 4326
}
```

Using the line:

```
ProjectionInfo source = shapefile.Projection;
```

...gets the projection information from the shapefile (in my case OSGB1936) and converting from this to 4326 works for me.
Hopefully this will help anyone else who is trying to convert from OSGB1936 (27700) to WSG84 (4326).